# Возможен ли взлом RSA шифрования на квантовом компьютере?

Tags: шифрование, rsa

Часто в СМИ вижу заголовки типо

> Как квантовый компьютер может взломать современные системы шифрования

Еще давно читал статью на [Хакер.ру](https://xakep.ru/2012/12/28/59888/) по мотивам [этого](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25375/why-not-use-larger-cipher-keys) вопроса. И меня очень поразил этот  [ответ](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25392)
Вот его часть в переводе.

> Одним из следствий закона второго термодинамики является то, что для представления информации необходимо некоторое количество энергии. Запись одиночного бита, изменяющая состояние системы, требует количества энергии не меньше чем kT; где Т — абсолютная температура системы и k — постоянная Больцмана. (Не волнуйтесь, урок физики уже почти закончен.)

> Приняв, что k = 1,38 * 10<sup>-16</sup> эрг/K, и что температура окружающей вселенной 3,2K, идеальный компьютер, работая при 3,2K, потреблял бы 4,4 * 10<sup>-16</sup> эрга всякий раз, когда он устанавливает или сбрасывает бит. Работа компьютера при температуре более низкой, чем температура космического пространства, потребовала бы дополнительных расходов энергии для отвода тепла.

> Далее, энергия, излучаемая нашим Солнцем за год, составляет около 1,21 * 10<sup>41</sup> эргов. Это достаточно для выполнения 2 * 10<sup>56</sup> перемен бита в нашем идеальном компьютере, а этого, в свою очередь, хватит для того, что бы 187-битовый счетчик пробежал все свои значения. Если мы построим вокруг Солнца сферу Дайсона и перехватим без всяких потерь всю его энергию за 32 года, мы сможем получить компьютер для вычисления 2192 чисел. Конечно, энергии для проведения каких-нибудь полезных вычислений с этим счетчиком уже не останется.

> Но это только одна жалкая звезда. При взрыве типичной сверхновой выделяется около 10<sup>51</sup> эргов. (В сто раз больше энергии выделяется в виде нейтрино, но пусть они пока летают). Если всю эту энергию удастся бросить на одну вычислительную оргию, то все свои значения сможет принять 219-битовый счетчик.

> Эти числа не имеют ничего общего с самой аппаратурой, они просто показывают максимальные значения, обусловленные термодинамикой. Кроме того, эти числа наглядно демонстрируют, что вскрытие грубой силой 256-битового ключа будет невозможно, пока компьютеры построены из обычной материи и располагаются в обычном пространстве.

Если не ошибаюсь то Солнце за год производит энергии больше чем люди за всю свою историю. Вот и получается что даже при идеальном компьютере попросту не хватит энергии на перебор всех возможных комбинация. 
Я понимаю что квантовые вычисления строятся совсем на других принципах. Но неужели они будут потреблять в сотни а то и в тысячи раз меньше энергии на свои операции? 
САБЖ.
Возможен ли взлом в реальности, или это все только теория?

Comment: что то у меня складывается впечатление, что автор сего опуса считает, что квантовый компьютер просто быстро-быстро перебирает числа в цикле (то есть, просто реализует for), А о суперпозиции и других моментах как то забылось.

Comment: эти рассуждения относятся к брутфорсу AES… с RSA они имеют чуть больше общего, чем ничего…

Comment: И да, квантовые вычисления ни как не угрожают безопасности AES, но стоит помнить, что пока нет строго доказательства, что не существует достаточно эффективного способа взлома AES обычными методами… хотя за последние 30 с лишним лет таковой ни кому не удалось продемонстрировать…